# How can i combine a function of a arguments with one of b arguments to a function of a+b arguments?

Tags: variables, arguments, python-3.7

I try to create functions to fit them on data with `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` .
If i want to take account of the background noise in the data with e.g. a linear function I combine my fitting function with this linear function like:

```
return (lambda x, *connected_parameters: self.function(x, *connected_parameters[1:self.param_count]) +
   function(x, *connected_parameters[self.param_count:-1]))
```

where self.function is my fitting function and function can be (lambda x, m, b: m*x + b) and x represents the set I want to fit on. The returned function is not working for optimize.curve_fit because using the asterisc symbol curve_fit now thinks there are only two arguments.

Is there a way to define the exact number of arguments depending on the noise function i want to use?

This is my first question, so sorry if I made some mistakes.
Best regards

**I get the following error message:**

> File "C:\Users\Hans\source\repos\pyQTGraph\pyQTGraph\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py", line 683, in curve_fit
>       raise ValueError("Unable to determine number of fit parameters.")
>   ValueError: Unable to determine number of fit parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I just recognized that I want the new function to have a+b-1 arguments because the both combined functions share one argument. It's x.